# What is meant by unstructured data? In the field of using ETL tools to work on data?

Tags: csv, edi

A teammate and I were discussing our work experience and he said he'd worked in the tool called Informatica. His work involved working on extracting required information from EDI files and transforming them and then loading them into the databases.
He said EDI files have unstructured data as opposed to formats like .CSV and .SQL and that in EDI files the columns are separated by the '|' symbol.

In my opinion I do not see any difference between EDI and CSV only the CSV is ',' separated and EDI is '|' separated then why would EDI files be classified as unstructured data?

Comment: "EDI" is a very generic term. Looking at [the EDI tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/edi/info), "Electronic Data Interchange is the transmission of **structured data** directly from one computer system of one organization to the computer system of another organization." The structure of the data has to be completely specified, or else the receiving system won't know what to do with it.

Comment: So do you mean that its not exactly true that EDI files are unstructured?

Comment: What example can be given for unstructured data then?
Yes, what you said makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Years ago I inherited an EDI project where a database report was sent, and we extracted the data based on line numbers and fixed-width substrings. It was very fragile, but the report format was specified and it was all we had to work with.

Comment: think you ar not clear about 'structured'. My interpretation about structured is 'the syntax semantics of the file is well described'. That is generally true for edi (as it has to be understand by another organization), and often true for csv - but not always. The body of an email as written by a person is mostly considered not structured. The header of a email is structured. HTML is structured - but the content is normally not structured. Might ber that teammate thinks of 'tabular data' as structured, which is true but does not mean edi is unstructured. Edi is moslty not tabular data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditional EDI is NOT unstructured.  EDI typically follows some kind of standard (X12, EDIFACT, TRADACOMS, etc) that specifically define what the structure of the data is.  XML, CSV, and delimited files are also structured.  They have a defined field delimiter, and a record terminator.

An example of unstructured data would be an Excel file that has multiple pieces of data in a proprietary format.  There would be no record identifiers, and a data parser wouldn't be able to understand what the data is.  It would appear as a stream of data / text, but wouldn't have any context a mapper would need to translate/integrate.  A Word document or PDF could also be considered as "unstructured".